# How to map two fields to one field in another database column in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to map field firstUser and secondUser in class Channel to field Id in class User but I don't know how to do that. Please help me! Here is my code.....

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_user")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    @NotNull(message = "Firstname can not be null")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    @NotNull(message = "Lastname can not be null")
    private String lastName;

 .....
 }

@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_message_channel")
public class Channel {

    private int firstUser;
    private int secondUser;

    @Column(name = "channel_uuid")
    private String channelId;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp createdDate;

......
}
```

Comment: check `@OneToOne` and `@JoinColumn`

Comment: There are many JPA docs on the internet that tell you how to model a 1-1 relation. Is internet search broken ? http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#one_one_relations

Comment: Thank you. It is not because of the internet search is broken but because it is new to me and I have just research about 1 week so..... that's why I asked. And It's better than stay silence.

Comment: Hi Leang, take a look at this link then, read all the relations (OneToOne (OTO), OTM,MTO,MTM) it doesn't take much time and see which relation you need more to use, [https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#JPA_Relationship_Types ] , it's also new to me and i'm trying to learn it too, sometimes i get confuse and don't know what should i do and any clue could help! i hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you so much @Reza Payambari. It confuses me also sometimes I don't know which relational I should use. So I did research and It doesn't help much so I need someone to ask in order to understand it clearly and someone don't know about that. Anyway thank you again. :D

Comment: I meant that you better check the examples in the link, with samples you could figure which annotation is better to use.

Comment: in this case, if you want to use 1 ID for firstuser and seconduser, then i would go on OneToMany annotation on ID field and exact opposite for the users.

Comment: then take a look at this sample, it will helps [ https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#OneToMany ]

Comment: but i wonder why you instead of `private int firstuser;` , don't try `private User firstuser;`

Comment: @Reza Payambari I tried with your solution and it worked. thank you so much. :D

Comment: Happy that i could help! Your Welcome! ;)

Comment: It would be also nice to mark this Topic as Answered, then others could also see it as a completed Topic and not as a not answered Topic. Best Regards.